# ParametricPlot or Plot give “is not a real number at” next to maximize plotting

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

I'm doing a problem of maximizing a function (BR1) that is based on another function (BF1) and its graphical representation but I get the error "NMaxime: The function value 1.7823 + 0.535011i is not a real number at".

Due to my little knowledge in the program I have not been able to correct or solve this problem.

```
ρ1c1[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := 1 + x ((1/(x - (c/n)^(1/α))) + (1/(-x + (c/m)^(1/α))))
ρ1c2[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := 1 - x (n/c)^(1/α)
ρ1c3[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := 0 c
ρ1c4[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := 0 c
π1c1[n_, m_, c_,x_, α_] := (n ρ1c1[n, m, c, x, α]/x)
π1c2[n_, m_, c_,x_, α_] := (n ρ1c2[n, m, c, x, α]/x)
π1c3[n_, m_, c_,x_, α_] := (n ρ1c3[n, m, c, x, α]/x)
π1c4[n_, m_, c_,x_, α_] := (n ρ1c4[n, m, c, x, α]/x)
PU2[n_, m_, c_,x_, α_] := (x + (((n/c)^(-2/α))/x) - (n/c)^(-1/α))^-α
PU1[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := c (-x (-2 + x (m/c)^(1/α)))^-α
PU1Max[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := c x^-α
PU2Max[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := c x^-α
```

(*PROFIT FUNCTION*)

```
 BF1[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := Piecewise[{{π1c1[n, m, c, x, α], 
 n <= Abs[PU1[n, m, c, x, α]] && 
  m <= Abs[PU2[n, m, c, x, α]] && 
  n < PU1Max[n, m, c, x, α] && 
  m < PU2Max[n, m, c, x, α]}, {π1c2[n, m, c, 
  x, α], 
 m > Abs[PU2[n, m, c, x, α]] && 
  n < PU1Max[n, m, c, x, α]}, {π1c3[n, m, c, 
  x, α], 
 n > Abs[PU1[n, m, c, x, α]] && 
  m < PU2Max[n, m, c, x, α] }, {π1c4[n, m, c, 
  x, α], 
 n >= PU1Max[n, m, c, x, α] && 
  m >= PU2Max[n, m, c, x, α]}}];
```

(*The Best Response*)

```
 BR1[n_] := Maximize[BF1[Subscript[p, 1], Subscript[p, 2], c, x, α][[1, 
 1]], n];
```

(*Plot the best Response*)

```
 x = 1;
 c = 1;
 α = 0.4;
 BR12 = ParametricPlot[{Subscript[p, 2],BR1[Subscript[p, 1]]}, {Subscript[p, 2], 0, 1}]
```

What will be the reason for the errors and do not graph the results?

```
 Unset::norep: Assignment on Subscript for Subscript[p, 1] not found.

 Unset::norep: Assignment on Subscript for Subscript[p, 2] not found.

 NMaximize::nrnum: The function value 1.7823 +0.535011 I is not a real number at {Subscript[p, 1]} = {-1.10131}.

General::stop: Further output of NMaximize::nrnum will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

Comment: Don't use subscript. Replace `Subscript[p,2]` with `p[2]` or `p2`. Apart from that, I think you have some fractional powers of negative numbers in `PU1` and `PU2` for example: `PU1[2, 3, .1, .3, .4]` evaluates to `0.00270022 - 0.00831042 I`. You need to impose constraints on the maximization to avoid these bad values or check your formulas are correct.

Comment: You are not feeding values into your maximize. You should write `BR1[p1_, p2_, c_, x_, α_] := Maximize[BF1[p1, p2, c, x, α], n][[1]]` then use it as a function from the plot. You should not pass in n_ either. And  when you plot, you don't seem to provide a range for p1.

Comment: Thanks for the help.
Regarding the query, I expected the graph to be in the positive quadrant of both the abscissa and the ordinate.
Another point is that I don't understand "n", no value is assigned to it, so how does it not change the graph?

Comment: You are trying to find the n that maximizes BF1 for a given {p1,p2} correct? My BR1 returns {the max value, n}. The parametric plot gives you all points {max value, n} for various p1 and p2.

Comment: I was trying to find p1 = f (p2) (p1 as a function of p2), and this being able to graph it, for values of x, c and alpha

Comment: That is to say, all the described functions should be in this way F [p1_, p2_, c_, x_, \ [Alpha] _]

Comment: I've updated my answer. Please take a look. p1 is a function of p2. The p1 (aka n)  is constrained > 0 to avoid negative values that caused the problem.  I used a table of values instead of `ParametricPlot` because that would be too slow.

Comment: Yes, I expected such a result, thank you.
One last question, if you wanted to graph through the ParametricPlot, how would it be?

Comment: It would be slow but  you could either do `Plot[BR1[p2, c, x, \[Alpha]], {p2, 0, 1}]` or you could do `ParametricPlot[{p2, BR1[p2, c, x, \[Alpha]]}, {p2, 0, 1}]`

Comment: Thank you, too much !!!

Answer (score 2):

Let me know if this is the output you were expecting:

```
ρ1c1[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := 1 + x ((1/(x - (c/n)^(1/α))) + (1/(-x + (c/m)^(1/α))))
ρ1c2[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := 1 - x (n/c)^(1/α)
ρ1c3[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := 0 c
ρ1c4[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := 0 c
π1c1[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := (n ρ1c1[n, m, c, x, α]/x)
π1c2[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := (n ρ1c2[n, m, c, x, α]/x)
π1c3[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := (n ρ1c3[n, m, c, x, α]/x)
π1c4[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := (n ρ1c4[n, m, c, x, α]/x)
PU2[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := (x + (((n/c)^(-2/α))/x) - (n/c)^(-1/α))^-α
PU1[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := c (-x (-2 + x (m/c)^(1/α)))^-α
PU1Max[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := c x^-α
PU2Max[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := c x^-α
BF1[n_, m_, c_, x_, α_] := Piecewise[{{π1c1[n, m, c, x, α], 
     n <= Abs[PU1[n, m, c, x, α]] && 
      m <= Abs[PU2[n, m, c, x, α]] && 
      n < PU1Max[n, m, c, x, α] && 
      m < PU2Max[n, m, c, x, α]}, {π1c2[n, m, c, x, α], 
     m > Abs[PU2[n, m, c, x, α]] && 
      n < PU1Max[n, m, c, x, α]}, {π1c3[n, m, c, x, α], 
     n > Abs[PU1[n, m, c, x, α]] && 
      m < PU2Max[n, m, c, x, α]}, {π1c4[n, m, c, x, α], 
     n >= PU1Max[n, m, c, x, α] && 
      m >= PU2Max[n, m, c, x, α]}}];
BR1[m_, c_, x_, α_] := First[Maximize[{BF1[n, m, c, x, α], n > 0}, n]];
With[{x = 1, c = 1, α = 0.4},
 results = Table[{p2, BR1[p2, c, x, α]}, {p2, 0.001, 1, .025}];
 ListLinePlot[results, AspectRatio -> 1, AxesLabel -> {p2, p1}, PlotStyle -> Thick]
 ]
```

[image]